# Mushroom Armor In decline?

Tags: small-world-underground

Can you still generate more Mushroom Armor while in decline? What about the turn you go into decline? There is a little disagreement about how to interpret the rules.

> For each Mushroom Forest Region you occupy at the end of your Conquest phase, take 1 Mushroom Armor from the tray in your hand. Deploy these Mushroom Armors in any of your Region(s), during your Troop Redeployment phase. Each Armor placed in a Region augments that Region's defense by 1, even when In Decline. These markers do not count as Race tokens (for instance a single Race token with 1 or more Shields in a Region could still be Vampirized). You can stack multiple Mushroom Armor in the same Region. Remove the Armor and discard them back in the tray when you abandon the Region or an enemy conquers it. Otherwise keep it in play as long as your Shield troops are on the board.

Edited for full rules.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't generate more Mushroom Armor in decline.  From the rules on entering in Decline:

> To do so, the player flips his current Race banner upside down, so
>   that the duotone In Decline side becomes visible to all, and discards
>   the Special Power badge that was associated with it as that Special
>   Power badge is no longer in effect, unless dictated otherwise (e.g.
>   Muddy, Reborn, Royal, etc…).

As for the turn you go into Decline, the rules for Shield state **"For each Mushroom Forest Region you occupy at the end of your Conquest phase"**.  Back to the rules for Decline: **"The player can make no conquests during the turn his race goes into decline; his turn ends immediately after scoring!"**

Basically you don't even get a Conquest phase on the turn you go into Decline, much less any new Mushroom Armor...

Comment: There is some confusion in our play group, I think mainly due to the wording on the "cheat sheet", which has the first few sentences concatenated into a single sentence. It was argued that the "...even when in decline" applied to everything.

Comment: @aslum If it's the sentence ending "...augments that Region's defense by 1, even when in Decline", it feels clear that that's specifically about the defensive powers of the Armor, not every aspect of the Shield Special Power.  Though I do say where your playgroup is coming from.